# Downloading Excel file from XMLHTTP request instead of opening IE and using IUIAutomation

Tags: excel, vba, automation

I have a macro set up to open IE and input fields for a query, then using UIUAutomation save the file to downloads and loop through downloads and open the file. I was wondering if its possible to use an XMLHTTP request to essentially do the same thing and save an excel file.

This is for a macro that is run often and speed and less errors are the goal. I've used MSXML2.SERVERXMLHTTP.6.0 to "POST" / "GET" before but can't figure out how to download an excel file, or if that's even possible.

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias 
"FindWindowExA" _
(ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpsz1 As String, _
ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long

Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetUserName Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias _
"GetUserNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As Long) As Long

Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal Milliseconds As 
LongPtr)

Function Sleeper(num As Integer)
  Sleep num
End Function

Public Sub AddReference()

ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromFile 
"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\UIAutomationCore.dll"

End Sub

Sub Pull_Query()

Dim i As Long, RC As Long, LMD As String
Dim ie As Object, LatestFile As String
Dim wbQuery As Workbook, count As Integer
Dim down_fp As String
Dim fpath As String,
Dim wbp As Workbook, filedl As String
Dim wsp As Worksheet, user As String
Dim LatestDate As String
Dim uia As IUIAutomation, h As Long
Dim uie As IUIAutomationElement
Dim iCnd As IUIAutomationCondition
Dim Button As IUIAutomationElement
Dim InvokePattern As IUIAutomationInvokePattern

Const URL = "******URL*******"

'Set IE and load the page
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate URL

While ie.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

'Search for field
ie.document.getElementById("***ID***").Value = "54000"
ie.document.getElementById("***ID***").OnChange

'This starts the download
ie.document.getElementById("***ID***").Click
While ie.ReadyState <> 3: DoEvents: Wend

tryagain:
  Sleeper (250)

Set uia = New CUIAutomation
h = ie.hwnd 'Clng(ie.hWnd)
h = FindWindowEx(h, 0, "Frame Notification Bar", vbNullString)
If h = 0 Then
GoTo tryagain
count = count + 1
If count > 5 Then Exit Sub
End If

Set uie = uia.ElementFromHandle(ByVal h)
Set iCnd = uia.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, "Save")
Set Button = uie.FindFirst(TreeScope_Subtree, iCnd)
Set InvokePattern = Button.GetCurrentPattern(UIA_InvokePatternId)
InvokePattern.Invoke

ie.Quit

user = ReturnUser()
down_fp = "C:\Users\" & user & "\Downloads"

filedl = Dir(down_fp & "\*filename*")
Do While Len(filedl) > 0
LMD = FileDateTime(down_fp & "\" & filedl)
If LMD > LatestDate Then
    LatestFile = filedl
    LatestDate = LMD
End If
filedl = Dir
Loop

Workbooks.Open (down_fp & "\" & LatestFile)

etc...

End Sub


Public Function ReturnUser()
Dim strUser As String, x As Integer
strUser = Space$(256)
x = GetUserName(strUser, 256)
strUser = RTrim(strUser)
ReturnUser= Left(strUser, Len(strUser) - 1)
End Function
```

This is what I'm used to as far as XMLHTTP so not sure how to change this to download excel file.

```
Set xHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.SERVERXMLHTTP.6.0")

    xHTTP.Open "POST", LoginURL, False
    xHTTP.setRequestHeader "content-type", "application/x-www-form- 
    urlencoded"

xHTTP.setRequestHeader "accept", "text/xml/html"
xHTTP.setRequestHeader "accept-charset", "utf-8, iso_8859-1"

xHTTP.setRequestHeader "userid", *UserID*
xHTTP.setRequestHeader "password", *Password*

xHTTP.send *request*
ResponseXML = xHTTP.responseText
```

Comment: is there an url associated with the download itself?

Comment: Yes, a url is there. I took it out because it is private.